# How to specify a source and a target on the function using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, mousehover

I need this function to change the border color of a form when the mouse hovers over a button. I got the expected result, but the function affects all page forms. I would like to determine which button affects each form.

How can I specify the source ID and target ID in the function?

[View demo](https://jsfiddle.net/YShs2/313/)

```
<head>
    <script>
        function chbg(color) {
            document.getElementById('b').style.backgroundColor = color;
            document.getElementById('d').style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('white')">A - This should effect B only</div>
    <div id="b">B - This is neutral</div>
    <div id="c" onmouseover="chbg('blue')" onmouseout="chbg('white')"> C - This should effect D only</div>
    <div id="d">D - This is neutral</div>
</body>
```

Update:

Solved! Thank you guys for the help.

[View solution](https://jsfiddle.net/YShs2/314/)

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/YShs2/310/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward, by adding extra parameters to the function:

```
function chbg(color, source, target) {
    document.getElementById(source).style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.getElementById(target).style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Example usage:

```
<div id="a" onmouseover="chbg('red', 'a', 'b')" onmouseout="chbg('white', 'a', 'b')">A - This should effect B only</div>
<div id="b">B - This is neutral</div>
<div id="c" onmouseover="chbg('blue', 'c', 'd')" onmouseout="chbg('white', 'c', 'd')"> C - This should effect D only</div>
<div id="d">D - This is neutral</div>
```

Comment: At first I tried the css ( : hover ) , but did not work for such a complex class .

Your solution worked great on my project . Simple and compact .

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the target using custom `data-*` attributes:

```js
function chbg(e) {
  document.querySelector(this.dataset.chbgTarget)
  .style.backgroundColor = this.dataset[
    'chbgColor' + (e.type == 'mouseover' ? 'Over' : 'Out')
  ];
}
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.chbg');
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) {
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', chbg);
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseout', chbg);
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="chbg"
     data-chbg-color-over="red"
     data-chbg-color-out="white"
     data-chbg-target="#b">
  A - This should effect B only
</div>
<div id="b">B - This is neutral</div>
<div id="c" class="chbg"
     data-chbg-color-over="blue"
     data-chbg-color-out="white"
     data-chbg-target="#d">
  C - This should effect D only
</div>
<div id="d">D - This is neutral</div>
```

If at mouseout you only want to remove the color, consider this:

```js
function chbg(e) {
  document.querySelector(this.dataset.chbgTarget)
  .style.backgroundColor =
    e.type == 'mouseover' ? this.dataset.chbgColor : '';
}
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.chbg');
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) {
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', chbg);
  els[i].addEventListener('mouseout', chbg);
}
```

```html
<div id="a" class="chbg"
     data-chbg-color="red"
     data-chbg-target="#b">
  A - This should effect B only
</div>
<div id="b">B - This is neutral</div>
<div id="c" class="chbg"
     data-chbg-color="blue"
     data-chbg-target="#d">
  C - This should effect D only
</div>
<div id="d">D - This is neutral</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the target element to the function using `this`.

First change your function to accept an element as a parameter:

```
function chbg(elem, color) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Then change your HTML to pass the element using the `this` keyword.

```
<div id="a" onmouseover="chbg(this, 'red')" onmouseout="chbg(this, 'white')">A - This should effect B only</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vz0o568w/)

However, for hover you should really be using CSS to change the background. For example:

```css
#a:hover {background-color: red;}
```

Comment: You didn't seem to put `chbg(this, 'red')`